# Postfix: How to Interpret a Spam Attack in Log

Tags: postfix, spam

Our Postfix mailserver was attacked by a spammer who was successful sending thousands of messages. Only ports 25 and 123 are open and the server is not an open relay, so I don't understand how the spammer was able to send spam.  I am aware of backscatter attacks but I don't know enough to tell from the log whether this is what happened in my case.

Here is the first few appearances in the log of the spammer purporting to be at `tbg4-finance.org`:

```
Sep 17 21:20:39 xxxx postfix/smtpd[16475]: connect from cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com[192.181.15.33]
Sep 17 21:20:40 xxxx postfix/smtpd[16462]: connect from 
cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com[192.181.15.33]
Sep 17 21:20:40 xxxx postfix/smtpd[16475]: 4FBFE15E604A: client=cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com[192.181.15.33]
Sep 17 21:20:40 xxxx postfix/smtpd[16462]: D677715E604F: client=cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com[192.181.15.33]
Sep 17 21:20:40 xxxx postfix/cleanup[16477]: 4FBFE15E604A: message-id=<>
Sep 17 21:20:40 xxxx opendkim[2589]: 4FBFE15E604A: cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com [192.181.15.33] not internal
Sep 17 21:20:40 xxxx opendkim[2589]: 4FBFE15E604A: not authenticated
Sep 17 21:20:40 xxxx opendkim[2589]: 4FBFE15E604A: no signature data
Sep 17 21:20:41 xxxx postfix/qmgr[10832]: 4FBFE15E604A: from=<info@tbg4-finance.org>, size=4380, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 17 21:20:41 xxxx postfix/smtpd[16475]: disconnect from cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com[192.181.15.33]
Sep 17 21:20:42 xxxx postfix/cleanup[16474]: D677715E604F: message-id=<>
Sep 17 21:20:42 xxxx opendkim[2589]: D677715E604F: cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com [192.181.15.33] not internal
Sep 17 21:20:42 xxxx opendkim[2589]: D677715E604F: not authenticated
Sep 17 21:20:42 xxxx opendkim[2589]: D677715E604F: no signature data
Sep 17 21:20:42 xxxx postfix/qmgr[10832]: D677715E604F: from=<info@tbg4-finance.org>, size=4354, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 17 21:20:43 xxxx postfix/smtpd[16462]: disconnect from cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com[192.181.15.33]
Sep 17 21:20:43 xxxx postfix/smtp[16492]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Sep 17 21:20:43 xxxx postfix/smtpd[16475]: connect from cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com[192.181.15.33]
Sep 17 21:20:43 xxxx postfix/smtp[16492]: D677715E604F: to=<??jpcvpa@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.201.26]:25, delay=3.3, delays=2/0.01/1.2/0.12, dsn=5.5.2, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.201$
Sep 17 21:20:44 xxxx postfix/cleanup[16477]: 0B4C215E6063: message-id=<20180918012044.0B4C215E6063@colo.richters.com>
Sep 17 21:20:44 xxxx postfix/bounce[16493]: D677715E604F: sender non-delivery notification: 0B4C215E6063
Sep 17 21:20:44 xxxx postfix/qmgr[10832]: 0B4C215E6063: from=<>, size=6346, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 17 21:20:44 xxxx postfix/qmgr[10832]: D677715E604F: removed
```

Here are a couple of queued attempts to deliver spam five days later:

```
Sep 22 13:34:52 xxxx postfix/smtp[13421]: 3EAC9174406F: to=<terry.kenny@blueyonder.co.uk>, relay=mx.tb.ukmail.iss.as9143.net[212.54.56.11]:25, delay=332231, delays=332227/0.9/3.3/0.14, dsn=4.1.0, status=deferred (host mx.tb.ukmail.iss.as9143.net[212.54.56.11] said: 421 4.1.0 logid=SMTPRC 421 MXIN400 Cannot validate your Mailfrom Domain tbg4-finance.org in DNS, adjust or retry later ;id=3lnvgKYxeSfOb3lnwgtDwQ;sid=3lnvgKYxeSfOb;mta=mx5.tb;d=20180922;t=193452[CET];ipsrc=24.138.106.49; (in reply to MAIL FROM command))

Sep 22 13:34:54 xxxx postfix/smtp[13399]: 5F64B15E60BA: to=<henk@uijterwaal.nl>, relay=mx3.xs4all.nl[194.109.24.134]:25, delay=403631, delays=403624/0.51/6.3/0.15, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host mx3.xs4all.nl[194.109.24.134] said: 450 4.1.8 <henk@uijterwaal.nl>... You cannot send mail from tbg4-finance.org since that domain cannot receive mail. See: http://postmaster.xs4all.nl/mx?d=tbg4-finance.org&c=NXDOMAIN (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

My question to postfix gurus is:

What do the logs reveal about the spammer's method of attack?

Answer (score 3):

When there's many things happening at the same time, you need to distinguish the messages from each other and investigate a single message at a time. Here, the only message with full logs is `D677715E604F`. We can exclude `opendkim` lines as there's no new information. Actually, everything relevant is here:

```
smtpd[16462]: D677715E604F: client=cpe-192-181-15-33.kya.res.rr.com[192.181.15.33]
qmgr[10832]: D677715E604F: from=<info@tbg4-finance.org>, size=4354, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
smtp[16492]: D677715E604F: to=<??jpcvpa@gmail.com>, 
    relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.201.26]:25, 
    delay=3.3, delays=2/0.01/1.2/0.12, dsn=5.5.2, 
    status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.201$
bounce[16493]: D677715E604F: sender non-delivery notification: 0B4C215E6063
qmgr[10832]: D677715E604F: removed
qmgr[10832]: 0B4C215E6063: from=<>, size=6346, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

- You get mail from `<info@tbg4-finance.org>` to `<??jpcvpa@gmail.com>`. Despite the client should be an unknown third party and the domain `tbg4-finance.org` is non-existent, your server is willing to deliver it. This means **your server is an open relay**.
- The `status=bounced` is a *connection-stage rejection* from Gmail. However, your server is willing to send a *non-delivery notification* based on that rejection, queued as a new message `0B4C215E6063`. This means **your server is a backscatterer**, too.

To answer your question, the method of your spammer was using your server as an open relay, targeting Gmail. While the server would have been a suitable target for sending backscatter, this wasn't the case, because there's no use to send anything to a non-existent domain. Still, you need to fix both of these conditions.

Comment: I agree with above.  Re prevention.  We have a firewall that sits in front of our Postfix servers which have ACLs to prevent non stated IP addresses using those ports.   Postfix is also configured to use SASL authentication, this then is also configured to only allow mail to be sent from IP address that appear in the `mynetworks` variable within /etc/postfix/main.cf . You can use a tool called qshape to see how postifx is distributing the messages and postcat -q "messageid" to view the message e.g `postcat -q D677715E604F`

Comment: Usually a mail server needs to accept incoming mails from anywhere, too. It's the Postfix configuration where you specify what's local, what to relay etc. No need for extra firewalls and gadgets.

Comment: In our case we create email using a 3rd party platform for mailshots but due to already warm IP reputation (and cost) we relay through our own mail servers so we only want to allow relay via the specified 3rd parties IP's.  Our firewall is locked down by default and then we open up as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Esa for your comments.  Although I agree that it looks like my server is an open relay, every test I have done (more than a dozen) suggested that it is not.  For example, the 
telnet IPADDRESS 25 test results in "554 5.7.1 <address@anotherdomain.com>: Relay access denied"

Comment: There's something that allows unwanted relay, so it's partly open. It might be that your test cases didn't take everything into account.

Comment: @EsaJokinen  Any suggestions where to look for clues on how my server might be partly open?  The tests I did, by the way, included online tools such as MxToolBox, AppRiver and others.